# How can I init accordion in Magento 2 on swatches, on product page

Tags: javascript, magento

I want to make an accordion for the swatches on the product page.

The switches are built into the file `Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js`

I did a mixin over the `_RenderControls` function and changed the `html` structure a bit compared to the original structure.

**CODE JS (via mixin)**

```
  container.append(
    '<div class="' + classes.attributeClass + ' ' + item.code + '" ' +
    'attribute-code="' + item.code + '" ' +
    'attribute-id="' + item.id + '">' +
    label +
    '<div class="init-accordion" >' +
    '<div data-role="collapsible">' +
    '<div class="title-accordion" data-role="trigger">titlu</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="content-accordion" data-role="content">' +
    '<div aria-activedescendant="" ' +
    'tabindex="0" ' +
    'aria-invalid="false" ' +
    'aria-required="true" ' +
    'role="listbox" ' + listLabel +
    'class="' + classes.attributeOptionsWrapper + ' clearfix">' +
    options + select +
    '</div>' + input +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'
);
```

I did not put the whole function because it is very long, I only put the part that differs from the original.

I want to initialize an accordion (according to the [Magento documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html)) on this swatch structure.

The problem is that the accordion does not initialize because the switches are still loaded on the page.

In the template, I would initialize like this

**CODE PHTML:**

```
<script>
    require(['jquery', 'domReady', 'accordion'], function($, domReady){
        domReady(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(".init-accordion").accordion({
                    "active": [1, 2],
                    "collapsible": true,
                    "openedState": "active",
                    "multipleCollapsible": true
                });
            }, 3000);
        });
    })
</script>
```

I used setTimeout and it works, but I want without it.

Do you have any idea how I can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: this could help you https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html